# Figuring out mininum/maximum clock frequency [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, frequency, clock-speed

I made my first design in VHDL with arctgs and sums and now I'm trying to synthesize it into an FPGA.

However, before that I need to understand more about:

1. How to discover how many clock cycles my design takes?
2. How can I discover the maximum (is there a minimum also?) frequency that my design accepts?

Can someone give me some guidelines please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't discover how many cycles it takes, you design that into the circuit.

You set your maximum clock speed target via a "timing constraint" (useful search term), and the synthesis tool will try to achieve that, or report which bits of the circuit fail to meet that timing. If you are using proper synchronous design, there will be no minimum speed.

If there are failures, you rewrite those bits so they are faster - if necessary, adding a clock cycle and splitting them across both cycles.

If you meet your speed goals with ease, Place&Route will proceed smoothly. If they don't, you go round the same loop again.

Answer (score 3):

Design synthesis is mostly devided into 3 steps: synthesis, mapping and place&route.

Synthesis can tell you estimated delays and compute a clock frequency. But the real frequency is only known after place&route (if the tool knows the wire delays).

To do so, the tool (static timing analyzer - STA) needs a set of timing constraints. After analysis the tool knows if your desired clock frequency can operate safely.

How many clock cycles are needed for a calculation depends on your algorithm / VHDL code.